# Time Format Problem with Arrow and Datetime

Tags: python, date

I have list of datetime objects. I want to group them to five minute intervals. My code is here:

````
```
count_array = [] #to simplify things, count the distructions happened in that 5-minute time range
l = len(date_array)

for timeRange in arrow.Arrow.interval('minute', start, end, 5):
    count = 1
    range_0 = timeRange[0].format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')
    range_0 = datetime.strptime(range_0, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')
    range_1 = timeRange[1].format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm")
    range_1 = datetime.strptime(range_1, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm")

    for i in range(0, l):
        if date_array[i] >= range_0 & date_array[i] <= range_1:
            count = count + 1
    count_array.append([timeRange[0], count])
```
````

Error is this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-86d69bb02cdf> in <module>
      5     count = 1
      6     range_0 = timeRange[0].format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')
----> 7     range_0 = datetime.strptime(range_0, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')
      8 
      9     range_1 = timeRange[1].format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    576     format string."""
--> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    357     if not found:
    358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 359                          (data_string, format))
    360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '04-06-2020 08:00' does not match format 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm'
```

I dont what is wrong because the line "range_0 = timeRange[0].format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')" and following line "range_0 = datetime.strptime(range_0, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm')" have the same format strings. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.